# Has anyone used Emojis in CiviMail subject/body?

Tags: civimail

I am curious if anyone has used Emojis in CiviMail content. I just tried a test mailing with an Emoji in the subject and message body, which show up fine in the editor but do not appear in the test message in my inbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@laryn the short answer is that for this to work your database needs to be changed. CiviCRM by standard sets things to be utf8_unicode_ci. You will need to convert database to utf8mb4_unicode_ci to allow for Emojis and you would need to change the setNames call in CiviCRM to be utf8mb4 as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814293/how-to-insert-utf-8-mb4-characteremoji-in-ios5-in-mysql

Comment: So -- not supported without some hacking, at least at this point! Thanks.

Comment: Update: converting CiviCRM tables to `utf8mb4` is in the roadmap: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/wikis/utf8mb4

Comment: Perhaps it would help to vote for https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/339 to remember to go for it?