# How do folks handle email preview text?

Tags: civimail, email, mosaico

When sending a CiviMail message, users sometimes want to customize the preview text for email clients - which is good practice. (The preview text shows up under the Subject in many email clients.) Using the default mosaico pre-header, you end up with preview text of "Unsubscribe View in your browser...." [update: HomoTechsual notes that the Mosaico pre-header has a preview text option. But this has limitations as noted in the thread.]

It seems there are two ways to edit the preview text in Civi:

1. Creating a pre-header block with the text for the preview, but this will be visible in the text of the email, which often isn't ideal.
2. Creating a `<div style="display: none;">Preview text here</div>` before any other text in the email. This is not user-friendly and is easily forgotten by users who have the knowledge of how to do it.

Any other suggestions for handling this?

Potential feature request: I'd love to see an non-required field for Preview Text under the subject field for every mailing. And (okay, this is a different, related feature) it would be great if a Preview Text field and Subject line could accommodate emojis (as described [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15872/has-anyone-used-emojis-in-civimail-subject-body)). If Civi doesn't add these abilities, I'm concerned it will fall behind in user expectations compared to other mass mailers.

Comment: Would be useful to log this as a feature request at https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues

Comment: Mosaico already has this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently wrote an extension to handle this: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/mailingpreviewtext

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 4):

Mosaico 2.x on CiviCRM already has the feature to add "preview text" for emails.

[image: Email preview text on CiviCRM Mosaico 2.0-beta4]

This is handled in the default "versafix-1" template and any derivatives thereof by way of a hidden text field in the HTML.

Your supplemental question regarding Emoji is more difficult - the Mosaico library can handle Emoji however CiviCRM's database storage engine doesn't use UTF8MB4 and isn't setup to handle Emoji content at this time. There is an issue [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/339) however getting this change into CiviCRM core (which is where it would need to occur) is not simple nor a priority at this time.

Comment: The problem with this is that if users have a mosaico template that they want to reuse, they have to go into the Mosaico editor to make the change, rather than creating a mailing based on that Mosaico template. It's also only a solution if one uses a Mosaico template. Sending out a "normal" message or system workflow message, doesn't have this option easily accessible to the user.

Comment: That’s a valid point but it belongs on the Mosaico issue queue as a feature request. The current implementation is basically what comes in Mosaico - so there is currently no CiviCRM changes to that ‘bit’.

Comment: But I'm interested in seeing it implemented outside of Mosaico, as not every communication requires the extra steps of Mosaico. Of course, the Mosaico template builder would need to coordinate with the basic mail editor in this regard.

Comment: The Mosaico editor has nothing to do with the basic mail editor it is a replacement for it.

Comment: @PhilMoriceBrubaker for the more basic communication it’ll depend on how you’re sending it for how best to implement this but the place to start would be the feature requests area on GitLab

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how Mosaico is supposed to be used, but my experience of the workflow is: Create a template in Mosaico, Create a new mailing in CiviMail based on that Mosaico template, and then you are back in the basic mail editor to finalize your email but with the Mosaico subject and primary message dropped into the appropriate places. That's not so much a replacement but an augmentation, or a pre-formatter. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Mosaico replaces the old ‘Civimail’ workflow for mass/scheduled mailings.